# Can someone explain this C# syntax to me?

Tags: c#

Working on some code for an example from Unity's learning platform.

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(switchKey))
{
    mainCamera.enabled = !mainCamera.enabled;
    hoodCamera.enabled = !hoodCamera.enabled;
}
```

The code works in my game, but I'm not sure what the
`= !maincamera.enabled` or `!hoodCamera.enabled` does here.

Full code for context here:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float horizontalInput;
    private float forwardInput;
    private float speed = 20;
    private float turnSpeed = 25;

    public Camera mainCamera; 
    public Camera hoodCamera; 
    public KeyCode switchKey;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        // this gets player input
        horizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        forwardInput = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime * speed * forwardInput);
    
        // make car rotate left and right
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * Time.deltaTime * turnSpeed * horizontalInput);
       // move left or right:  transform.Translate(Vector3.right * Time.deltaTime * turnSpeed * horizontalInput);

      if (Input.GetKeyDown(switchKey))
      {
          mainCamera.enabled = !mainCamera.enabled;
          hoodCamera.enabled = !hoodCamera.enabled;
      }
   }
}
```

I followed the code from a solution to a challenge project, and the code works as intended. When the switchkey variable is pressed, it changes between a different camera only while the key is pressed.

Comment: ! = not,  so if mainCamera.enabled would be true, !mainCamera.enabled will be false.

Comment: It is used to replace this if(mainCamera.enabled){mainCamera.enabled = false}else{mainCamera.enabled = true}. In this case, it is used to switch the value to the oposite every time the key is pressed

Answer (score 0):

It's negating the value of the `enabled` field/property of `mainCamera` and `hoodCamera` respectively (setting its value to the negation of the current value... i.e.: `false` if it was `true`, and `true` if it was `false`)